# Would a point undefined on $f'(x)$ still be considered a critical point of $f(x)$ if it's undefined on $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus

My textbook defines a "critical point" as follows--

> For any function $f$, a point $p$ in the domain of $f$ where $f′(p)=0$ or $f′(p)$ is undefined is called a critical point of the function. In addition, the point $(p,f(p))$ on the graph of $f$ is also
>   called a critical point. A critical value of $f$ is the value, $f(p)$, at a critical point, $p$.

Suppose I am given function $f(x)=5x-3\ln(x)+2$. To get $f(x)$'s critical points, I would need to solve $f'(x)=0$ such that
$$f'(x)=5-\frac{3}{x}=0$$
$$5=\frac{3}{x}\to x=\frac{3}{5}$$

Evidently, $3/5$ is a critical point. However, the textbook definition also specifies critical points lie where **$f'(p)$ is undefined**. By that logic, would $x=0$ be considered a critical point of $f(x)$, since division by $0$ is impossible? My instinct tells me that $x=0$ *wouldn't* qualify as a critical point since it's also undefined for $f(x)$ itself, (i.e. $\ln 0$) but what are your thoughts? Is it possible for a point to be undefined at both $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$ and still be called a critical point?

Comment: Let's put some parentheses: "point $p$ in the domain of $f$ where $\mathbf{(}$$f'(p)=0$ or $f'(p)$ is undefined$\mathbf{)}$". It is true that it was ambiguous.

Comment: read carefully, $\mathbf {in\ the\ domain\ of}\ f:$(0, $\infty$)

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's possibly a better rewording:

> Let $f$ be a function with domain $D$, and let $p$ be a point in $D$. If $f'(p) = 0$ or $f'(p)$ is undefined, then $p$ is called a *critical point* of $f$.

This should highlight the ambiguity $-$ $p$ is a point in the domain of $f$ first and foremost, then if it also satisfies one of the two conditions, it gets to be a critical point.